# Adding Aloha Editor to Django Admin, jQuery compatibility issues ensue

Tags: jquery, django-admin, aloha-editor

I'm writing a personal blog in Django, and would like to include Aloha Editor into the admin panel. I have been following the instructions, which failed. I then tried other things, including putting a newer version of jQuery (instead of Django's 1.4.2) into my `/static/admin/js`, which only broke things*. It seems jQuery is not available when it's needed (at `document.ready`), but at any later point, enabling Aloha from console works... through django.jQuery.

```js
>>> django.jQuery('.vLargeTextField').aloha() //works
>>> $('.vLargeTextField').aloha() // does not work; jQuery 1.7.2 loaded by Aloha
```

My **templates/admin/base_site.html** (*relevant blocks*):

```html
{% block extrastyle %}
<link href="/static/admin/local-lib/alohaeditor-0.21.3/aloha/css/aloha.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
{% endblock %}

{% block extrahead %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.0.6/minified    /require.js"></script>
<script src="/static/admin/local-lib/alohaeditor-0.21.3/aloha/lib/aloha.js"
data-aloha-plugins="common/ui,
        common/format,
        common/list,
        common/link,
        common/highlighteditables">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Aloha.ready( function() {
  Aloha.jQuery('.vLargeTextArea').aloha();
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

*Breakage includes: Tabular inline is now wonky, collapsible fieldsets now have a bit different behaviour than with jQuery 1.4.2.

### Edit

It seems that the only real way of inserting Aloha into the admin panel is to put the last script in the `blockbots` (!!!) block, which is rendered under standard Django admin inclusions. Also, it is imperative to use the jQuery supplied by Aloha to work with Aloha, as the 1.8 I put in my `/static/admin` will not work. For Django's admin, I reverted to the supplied 1.4.2. However, new problems arose: The tooltips for Aloha bunch up at the bottom of the page, and do not disappear. Additionally, the console is littered with errors. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: What errors are displayed in the console?

Comment: See the second example in this comment (where I said "should always work for any project") https://github.com/alohaeditor/Aloha-Editor/issues/707#issuecomment-8152439

Comment: The problem is with the new jQuery (1.8.1), and errors look like this: `TypeError: f.curCSS is not a function 

...is),e=b.outerWidth(),c=b.outerHeight(),g=parseInt(f.curCSS(this,"marginLeft",tru...

aloha.js (line 875)`

Comment: Yes that's true, jQuery 1.8 isn't yet supported. https://github.com/alohaeditor/Aloha-Editor/issues/692

Answer (score 0):

You might try using a pre-built django integration package for aloha:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-aloha-edit,

Then use the HTMLField, or simply use the AlohaWidget and specify the backend. The HTMLField does important sanitation, but if you're only editing from the backend with trusted users this is not necessary, and you can just override the widget in the backend.

```
formfield_overrides = {
    models.TextField: {'widget': AlohaWidget(attrs={'style':'width:100%;max-width:800px;height:80ex;'})},
}
```

The advantage of this, is that the required js resources are automatically included - including the version of jQuery just for Aloha. (The two versions can act independently.)